# Relation between the $2^n$-Bockstein homomorphisms

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, group-homomorphism

The $2^n$-Bockstein homomorphism 
$$\beta_{2^n}:H^*(-,\mathbb{Z}/{2^n})\to H^{*+1}(-,\mathbb{Z}/2)$$ is associated to the short exact sequence
$$0\to\mathbb{Z}/2\to\mathbb{Z}/{2^{n+1}}\to\mathbb{Z}/{2^n}\to0$$
In particular, $\beta_2=Sq^1$ is the Steenrod square.

My question: what is the relation between $\beta_{2^n}$ and $\beta_{2^{n+k}}$ for $n\ge1$, $k>0$?

I guess 
$$\beta_{2^{n+k}}\alpha=\beta_{2^n}$$
where $\alpha:H^*(-,\mathbb{Z}/{2^n})\to H^*(-,\mathbb{Z}/{2^{n+k}})$ is induced from 
$$\mathbb{Z}/{2^n}\to\mathbb{Z}/{2^{n+k}}$$
which maps the generator of $\mathbb{Z}/{2^n}$ to $2^k$ times the generator of $\mathbb{Z}/{2^{n+k}}$.

Can you help me to prove or disprove it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are correct.  Consider the following map of short exact sequences
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \mathbb{Z}/2 @>>> \mathbb{Z}/2^{n+1} @>>> \mathbb{Z}/2^n @>>> 0 \\
@. @| @VVV @VVV @. \\
0 @>>> \mathbb{Z}/2 @>>> \mathbb{Z}/2^{n+k+1} @>>> \mathbb{Z}/2^{n+k} @>>> 0.
\end{CD}
$$

The connecting homomorphism induced by the first row is $\beta_{2^n}$, the connecting homomorphism induced by the second row is $\beta_{2^{n+k}}$, and the third vertical homomorphism induces what you call $\alpha$.

By the naturality of connecting homomorphisms, we have 
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
H^*(-, \mathbb{Z}/2^n) @>\beta_{2^n}>> H^*(-, \mathbb{Z}/2) \\
@V\alpha VV @| \\
H^*(-, \mathbb{Z}/2^{n+k}) @>>\beta_{2^{n+k}}> H^*(-, \mathbb{Z}/2),
\end{CD}$$
which proves your assertion.